# Is there a hidden or alternate ending for the game Limbo?

Tags: limbo

I just finished Limbo for the first time and was disappointed by the ending.  Is there an alternative or hidden ending?

Maybe if you get that achievement where you beat the game in one session while dying five times or less?

I also hit a key to exit the credits early, is there something after the credits?

Comment: Maybe it is just setting up a sequel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only thing you get after the credits is an achievement.

And no, there is no hidden ending in Limbo.  If you beat the game without dying once you'll get another secret egg (and is required to get 111% in the game, but there's no achievement for that), but otherwise there's no secret ending.

Answer (score 8):

Actually there is a secret level. It can be accessed after collecting all 10 hidden eggs

{This is ONLY on the PS3/PC or later versions of the game. (I play it on iOS and PC and it *does* work for this-i am not sure if they added it to the original Xbox version, but you should be able to find out if the "door" is there or not (see below...) }

After you have all of the eggs, go to chapter 26, just before the arthropod (the mosquito-insect you snatch a ride on.) Go in the dark past the spot where you get the "Alone in the Dark" achievement. You will see a big metal door with a circle of 10 candles in front of it where each candle represents an egg. Once all are lit the door will open and you can enter the "secret" level.

https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=113463434

Answer (score 1):

Actually I asked the developer about if there is a secret ending since the actually ending is disappointing, and the developer said that there is NO secret ending, but the actual ending sets up a second game, because did you notice that before the credits the ladder is fine, but afterwards the ladder is ripped in 2? If you didn't go back and check.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a 'false ending' that's referenced here where you almost reach the sister and a mind-worm leeches onto you and leads you away:

http://kotaku.com/the-most-depressing-theories-on-what-limbo-means-1724276367

This is under the heading `The Boy Is Stuck Forever, And The Ending Is A Trick.`

Answer (score -1):

yes there is. I found it.

Either that or I broke the universe but I passed the last puzzle by running through, not floating. I was taken to another puzzle. I quit that puzzle and got some juice and when i fired up the game again, i was back at the 'official' last puzzle again. At which point i floated through and it ended.

There is an alternate ending. And i'm pissed that i started to discover it and it didn't save that progress. I haven't found it again. But that it's there? Yes because i started playing it. YOU just haven't found it yet previous answerer. There is also an alternate series of levels. Everybody's found or knows about those. I haven't played them yet but a lot of people have (these people include many youtubers)

Comment: Unsubstantiated answer.