# In the ending, what happens to the boy and the girl?

Tags: limbo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can someone formulate a clear description of the ending of Limbo?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6329/can-someone-formulate-a-clear-description-of-the-ending-of-limbo)

Did both the boy and the girl die in the end?

After the animation where he found the girl ended, the game menu appeared. The scene behind it looked similar to the previous one. But there only were swarms of flies above the two patches of grass approximately where the kids stood just a moment before.

Comment: Good question (I +1'd it) as the same question popped in my mind when finishing the game. However, do we have to answer this kind of questions as I think letting this open is also part of the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many theories about the ending of Limbo. [This article](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/news/2010/07/limbos-ending-what-does-it-all-mean-we-explore.ars) gives a good summary.

Comment: Copy/Paste of the pretty much the entire text of the article is highly unlikely to be within the license they grant (or rather that they don't, their footer states: *The material on this site may not be reproduced, distributed, transmitted, cached or otherwise used, except with the prior written permission of Condé Nast Digital.*) and it is very unlikely to be considered fair usage (since it's all of it). Could this be paraphrased or trimmed to small exerts?

Comment: I thought giving it as a whole passage would be better for the sake of completeness and to prevent the loss from possible link rot; but I can just give the link without copying the content.

Comment: I do agree, but it's somewhat cheeky for us to pinch their entire work without permission.

Comment: Got it. I hope giving just the link would not be a problem.

Comment: The Wikipedia-entry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limbo_%28video_game%29#Plot_2 sums up the controversy pretty well, maybe that is better suited for a quote with their fair-reuse policy.

Comment: @bkzland actually Wikipedia uses a [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License), the same as all of Stack Exchange, so we *can* copy them verbatim as long as it is attributed to the source page correctly.